How to send simple HTTP 201 Created response using Swift-NIO
I am trying to create a server that can accept a file save it on server and send a 201 Created response.
Server has been made using Swift-NIO 2.65.0
I am successfully receiving the file as I can see the file save in the intended upload directory of the server but I do not understand how to simply send and HTTP 201 Created response with empty body.
Apples's Github examples are not doing a great job in explaining the code.
I tried
context.write()
context.channel.write()

I've seen similar issues to this one and what you may be missing is flush. You need to call either writeAndFlush() or write() then flush().

Thank you @dalton_c for the guidance however I have found the solution to my problem.
What I was doing wrong was a simple misspelling of the type alias OutboundOut
what I did was:-
typealias OutbountOut = HTTPServerResponsePart
instead of:-
typealias OutboundOut = HTTPServerResponsePart
which resulted in wrong signature of context of write being available.
After fixing this issue I am getting proper 201 created response.

I would very much recommend not using SwiftNIO directly for this task. SwiftNIO is very low-level. Maybe you want to use Vapor?

If however you really want to code it up in SwiftNIO (again, it will be much more work as it's low-level) you're in luck because there's literally a full SwiftNIO example server doing file uploads over at https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-examples/blob/main/backpressure-file-io-channel. It also has quite a lot of documentation in the README and in the code. And it has lots of tests too.
To make it return 201 Created instead of 200 OK, you'd just need to change this line from .ok to .created: https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-examples/blob/712f7f94bfd16d001b0b36e715588b22600e631c/backpressure-file-io-channel/Sources/BackpressureChannelToFileIO/SaveEverythingHTTPServer.swift#L102

I have found the solution to my problem.
What I was doing wrong was a simple misspelling of the type alias OutboundOut
What I did was:-
typealias OutbountOut = HTTPServerResponsePart
instead of:-
typealias OutboundOut = HTTPServerResponsePart
which resulted in wrong signature of context of write being available. After fixing this issue I am getting proper 201 created response.
